# How to use jQuery function on hover

Tags: jquery

I created jQuery function

```
function starsMouseMove(n) {
    var i = $(this).offset().left,
        t = Math.floor((n.pageX - i)),
        w;
    if (t > 0 && t < 20) {
        w = 20;
    } else if (t >= 20 && t < 40) {
        w = 40;
    } else if (t >= 40 && t < 60) {
        w = 60;
    } else if (t >= 60 && t < 80) {
        w = 80;
    } else if (t >= 80 && t <= 100) {
        w = 100;
    }
    $(".stars_width", $(this)).css("width", w + "%");
    $(this).parent().find('#rating-input').val(w / 10);
};
```

and then I try to use it on `hover`

```
$('.stars').hover(function (n) {
    starsMouseMove(n);
});
```

but I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

What's wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: `this` in function `starsMouseMove(n)` is `$('.stars')`

Comment: you should have logged `this`, you would have discovered it was `Window`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `this` within your `starsMouseMove` function does not refer to the element of the `hover` event selector, but instead the `window`. Therefore the `offset()` is returned as `undefined`, so calling the `left` property of that throws the error. If you want to maintain the scope of `this` within that function you can call it like this:

```
$('.stars').hover(starsMouseMove);
```

Alternatively if you'd prefer to keep the anonymous function (if it contains logic besides the call to `starsMouseMove` for example) you could use `$.proxy`:

```
$('.stars').hover(function(e) {
    $.proxy(starsMouseMove, this, e);
});
```

Or you could amend the function to accept a jQuery object as a parameter, and pass it in:

```
$('.stars').hover(function(e) {
    starsMouseMove(e, this);
});

function starsMouseMove(n, el) {
    var $el = $(el);

    // rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, I used the last solution, it works fine for me.